# Bootstrap datepicker stop changing year when press print Screen key of keyboard in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap's datepicker in my application. when I press the PrtScrn key on my keyboard it changes the year in the datapicker.

How can I stop this behavior from happening?

Here is my Directive code.

```
 .directive('datepicker', function(){
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel,$filter){
                 var dates = scope.$eval(attrs.datepicker);               
                if(dates[0].toDate !== null)
                {
                  var date =new Date(dates[0].toDate) ;
                  var toDate=(date.getDate()) + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' +  date.getFullYear();
                  var date1 =new Date(dates[0].fromDate) ;
                  var fromDate=(date1.getDate()) + '/' + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date1.getFullYear();
                }                
                if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

                ngModel.$render = function(){

                    element.val( ngModel.$viewValue || '' );
                }

                element.datepicker({
                    format    : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    autoclose : true,
                    //startDate : toDate,
                    endDate   : toDate
                });            

                function read() {
                    var value = element.val();
                  //  ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                }  
            }
        }
    });
```

This is html code

```
     <input 
    dynamic-name="field.name"
    datepicker="[{toDate:field.todate,fromDate :field.fromdate}]"                                                      readonly="field.isreadonly"
    type="text"
    placeholder ="{{field.placeholder}}"
    class="form-control"
    dynamic-validation = "field.validationtype"
    ng-model= "formVariables[field.name]"
    value="{{field.value}}"
    ng-required = "{{field.expression}}"
 />
```

Step to reproduce:

- Click on month or year.
- Then click right or left arrow of year.
- Press PrtScrn key of keyboard and observe the output year and months get change.

Expected result year or Month should not be change when press PrtScrn key.

Comment: I've used `Bootstrap's datepicker` also, but in my project, your problem is not occurred.. Um.. so weird.. can you post your code of controller or html? Or is there some code using key event in your project?

Comment: Thanks Canet Robern, i have updated my question with controller and html code .please check and let me know.

Comment: Can you share the modules what you are using?

Comment: I've tried your code in my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/r757rswp/ but I cannot find any errors.. Have you edited or modified js files? Or do you have any key event in your local code?

Comment: There is no any key event in my code. i've checked your https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/r757rswp/  but there is same problem occure. i'm using MAC or windows os . check this problem follow step. 1> click on month or year. 2> then click right or left arrow of year. 3> press PrtScrn key of keyboard and observe the output year and months get change . Expected result year or Month should not be change when press PrtScrn key.

Comment: Oh, I've finally reached the same problem! It did not happen before I chose the date, but when I chose a date and press PrtScrn key, it happened. And I've found the same problem occurred in my project. I'll check and if I find some solution, I'll post it to share with you. :)

Comment: Good to know , that you understood the problem. thanks for your co-operation.